# RequireJS is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

After much frustration, I finally decided to install `requirejs` via `npm`. However, even with this basic example, it still won't work.

```
define(function(require) {

var requirejs = require('node/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/requirejs/require');

requirejs.config({
    //Pass the top-level main.js/index.js require
    //function to requirejs so that node modules
    //are loaded relative to the top-level JS file.
    nodeRequire: require
});

requirejs(['http'],
function   (http) {
// code here
});


});
```

The error:

```
TypeError: requirejs is undefined @ test.js:7
```

If I replace the long path with just `require`, I get instead:

```
 TypeError: requirejs.config is not a function @ test.js:11
```

Comment: **<rant>** why in the world are you using require.js while you're already using node. **</rant>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a function with an argument of require.   Try changing your first line to function(somethingElse) and it should load.